# How to expand a nested column in pandas data frame and attach back to original dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe in the below format .

**Input**

```
df.head(3)

groupId  Gourpname  totalItemslocations
    7494732   A         {'code': 'DEHAM', 'position': {'lat': 53.551085, 'lon': 9.993682}}
    7494733   B         {'code': 'DEHAM', 'position': {'lat': 53.551086, 'lon': 9.993687}}
    7494734   A         {'code': 'DEHAM', 'position': {'lat': 53.552084, 'lon': 9.993682}}
```

**Expected Output**

```
roupId   Gourpname  totalItemslocations.code     totalItemslocations.position.lat    totalItemslocations.position.lon 
7494732   A              DEHAM                        53.551085                           9.993682
7494733   B              DEHAM                        53.551086                           9.993687
7494734   A              DEHAM                        53.552084                           9.993682
```

How can this be pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.Series` to explode the dictionary and `pd.concat` to merge it with other columns.

```
df = pd.concat([df.drop(['totalItemslocations'], axis=1), df['totalItemslocations'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df.drop(['position'], axis=1), df['position'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

groupId   groupname          code      lat         lon 
7494732       A              DEHAM    53.551085   9.993682
7494733       B              DEHAM    53.551086   9.993687
7494734       A              DEHAM    53.552084   9.993682
```